# Update Access Combo Box List of Values when a value is chosen

Tags: ms-access

I am building an Access database that schedules teachers at a tech school. I have a combo box that list teachers that are available each day.

When a supervisor is scheduling teachers they select a button that opens a continuous form. On the form is a combo box. The list of values for this combo box is derived from a query that in turn is a combination of two other queries.  One query is a list of days that teachers are off duty and the other is a list of lectures to which teachers are assigned. In sum, the query that results in the list of values looks to see which teachers are NOT off work and not scheduled to deliver another lecture on the same day in question.

What I would like to do is have, when an instructor is assigned to a lecture, have their name removed from the list of values for that day.  The goal is to have the list of values decrease as each teacher is scheduled for a lecture.  This will assist avoiding scheduling the same teachers for lectures that occur at the same time on the same day.  However, the teachers names still needs to appear in the list of values for every other day that they are at work and not scheduled to deliver a lecture.

How do I update the results of the query, the list of values for the combo box, to not include the teachers that are scheduled for other lectures on the same day?

Comment: Commit record to table then requery the combobox.

Comment: Edit question to post the combobox RowSource query if you need more help.